# Error in binary vector when increasing length R

Tags: r

Rewording question error produced in binary vector when placed into R

```
z2p<-c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ,0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ,1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1 ,0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ,1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1 ,1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0 ,1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ,1 ,0 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,0 ,1 ,1 ,1, 1 ,1 ,1, 1 ,0 ,1 ,1 ,0 ,1 ,0 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,0 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,0 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,0 ,1 ,1, 1 ,1, 1, 1, 1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,0 ,1 ,1, 1, 1 ,0 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,0 ,1 ,1, 0 ,1, 0 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,0 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,0 ,1 ,1, 1 ,1 ,0 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1, 0, 1,1 ,1 ,1 ,0 ,1 ,1 ,1, 1, 1 ,1 ,1 ,0 ,1 ,1 ,0 ,1 ,0 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,0 ,1 ,1,1 ,1 ,0 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,0 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,0 ,1 ,1 ,1, 1 ,0 ,1 ,1, 1, 1, 1 ,1 ,1 ,0 ,1, 1, 0 ,1 ,0 ,1, 1 ,1 ,0 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,0 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1, 0 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,0 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,0 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,0, 1 ,1, 0, 1, 0 ,1 ,1, 1, 0 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,0 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,0 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1, 1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,0 ,1 ,1, 1 ,1 ,0 ,1 ,1, 1 ,1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0 ,1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ,1 ,0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1,0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0 ,0 ,1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ,1 ,0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,0, 1 ,1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1 ,1 ,1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,0, 1, 1, 1 ,1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1 ,0 ,1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0 ,0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1 ,1 ,1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0 ,1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1 ,1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ,1 ,1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1 ,0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1 ,1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1 ,1 ,1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1 ,0 ,1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ,1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1 ,1 ,1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1 ,0 ,1 ,1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0 ,0 ,1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ,1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1,1 ,1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1, 1 ,1, 1, 1, 1 ,1 ,0 ,1 ,1 ,0 ,1 ,1 ,1, 1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,0 ,1 ,1 ,0 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1, 1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0 ,1 ,1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ,1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ,1 ,1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1 ,1 ,1, 1, 1,0, 1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,0 ,1 ,1 ,0 ,1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1 ,0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ,1 ,1, 1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,1,1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ,0 ,0 ,1, 1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1 ,1 ,1 ,1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1,1, 1, 1, 1 ,1 ,1, 1 ,1 ,1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1, 0, 1, 1 ,1, 1 ,1 ,1 ,0 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1, 1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,0 ,1 ,1 ,0 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,0 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,0 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1, 1, 1, 1 ,1, 1, 1 ,1 ,0, 1 ,1 ,0 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,0 ,1, 1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,0 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,0 ,1 ,1 ,0, 1 ,1 ,1, 1 ,0 ,1 ,1 ,1, 1, 1, 1 ,1, 1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,1 ,1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1,1 ,1 ,1, 1 ,1)

# The error occurs as mentioned
Error: unexpected numeric constant in:
"1,0, 1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,0 ,1 ,1 ,0 ,1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1 ,0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ,1 ,1, 1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0
1"
```

Comment: Is longer now. The issue was that the error only occurred in that length no more no less. However seems to be an issue of the platform where I do the code. Now however the one above produces a similar error but the code is fine.

Comment: Solved used R studio it seems much better as to compile code

Comment: Mostly due to spaces, if you remove them, it works. Seems R does a carriage return on a space somewhere when you paste this long line. I'm searching if there's a parameter somewhere

Comment: It is strange though. Running the code straight gives the empty argument error. Find and replace " " with "" seems to run fine.

Comment: @AkhilNair paste it in a file in Rgui, you'll see it does two lines, seems there's a cut on space at a certain length (3071 in my case by `nchar` of the first line in the file editor)

Comment: And with a first line of 3072 chars it works

Comment: Yeah good spot. Which would be why it wasn't working when 1 more argument was added.

Comment: @AkhilNair Yes, I suspect there's a point where the vector args match exactly the size of a buffer and so it's not continued on the next line.